# How to print a specified text using Quick Actions

Tags: macos, quickaction

I am trying to make a quick action to be able to paste a specified text (like: 'print('Hello')') on anywhere I can type. So I want to (using my TouchBar) click on a button which will then print a text on (for example Notes). Is there a way to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way

if you write this command in the AppleScript inside the Quick Actions, you can paste 'hello' so you just have to change 'hello'

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "hello"
end tell
```

But you need to allow the accessibility security for the app you want in system preferences > security& privacy > Privacy.
If the app is not shown in the list you can add it manually by pressing the + button right underneath.

Comment: But be aware to not give the access to apps you don't trust, because you are actually giving the access to control your computer.